# 7 Wonders Duel Pantheon : Can a player invoke a God during Age I?

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

From the 7 Wonders Duel Rules

> The first player begins Age I. On your turn, you must choose an
>   “accessible” card in the card structure and play it. An accessible
>   card is a card which isn’t partially covered by other cards.
>
> You can play the card you’ve chosen in one of three different ways:
>   1. Construct the Building
>   2. Discard the card to obtain coins
>   3. Construct a Wonder

A player can therefore build Wonders during Age I.

From the 7 Wonders Duel Pantheon rules

> During Age I, the players will choose the Divinities they will be able
>   to invoke during Ages II and III.

Later, in 7 Wonders Duel Pantheon rules

> The Divine Theater Wonder 
>   Reveal all of the cards from a Mythology
>   deck of your choice.  Choose one of the Divinities revealed this way
>   and activate it for free. Then stack the unused cards, in the order of
>   their choice. This Wonder is worth 2 victory points.

**The question**

Can a player build "The Divine Theatre" Wonder during Age I and activate a God from one the Mythology draw piles?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe you can activate a God in Age I using the Divine Theater.

> During Age I, the players will choose the Divinities they will be able to invoke during Ages II and III.

is taken from the Overview of the rules.  I think that's more just a general guide of what happens rather than a strict rule that prevents The Divine Theater from working.  I think if using The Divine Theater was in some way forbidden during Age I then that should be explicitly stated in the rules.  Note The Gate allows a player to use any god revealed from the top of any deck,  This was not chosen by a player to be able to be invoked during Ages II and III.  So if A God can be played that way (just not following the exact letter of the overview)  then I see no reason why The Divine Theater can not either.

Note your revealing all the cards from a 'Deck' so if you choose a category that only has 2 or 1 card left in the deck that that is all you reveal.  Note you return them in the order you choose, this is relevant for the Gate card.  I would also argue that as the cards are 'revealed' that your opponent will see the order they are returned.